# Can a warlock with Repelling Blast use Eldritch Blast to push 10 feet a creature of any size?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature

From the RAW ruling, unless I am missing official errata or clarifications documents from WotC  I do not see any size limitations to the use of the Repelling Blast power of Eldritch Blast.

So it means you could push back up to 10 feet a creature of any sizes regardless of any context, weight, mass or your own size ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### Yes. There is no restriction on creature size.

Which is what makes repelling blast a very nice invocation.

If you go to Combat rules in chapter 9, the 'shove' action has a size limitation.

> The target of your shove must be no more than one size larger than
> you, and it must be within your reach.(Basic Rules, p. 77)

The rules text for [repelling blast](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/warlock#EldritchInvocations-388) has no such limitation on the creature being hit with it.

> When you hit a creature with eldritch blast, you can push the creature
> up to 10 feet away from you in a straight line.

Why did I bring up Chapter 9?  Because not all DMs have played all classes nor memorized all class abilities. As an example, my brother (DM) had never seen a warlock in play that had repelling blast as an invocation. The first time I pushed a huge creature back (a hill giant) his response was "Isn't that too big for you to push back?" to which I replied "this invocation does not have the limitation that a shove does." He trusts me so off the road it went.

We played on and after the game I showed him the difference.  His response was to nod his head.

Comment: And if you are high level enough and hit the same creature with two blasts, can you push it away 20 feet ? or is it 10 feet per Spell ? Seems the writing indicates per spell not per spell attack, but i am not sure.

Comment: @KilrathiSly: [Asked and answered already](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/88025/28941).

Comment: @KilrathiSly per attack, so yeah, at level 18 you can push a creature back a total of 40 feet. Neat, though at that level you may be on the astral plane where distances are weird ...

Answer (score 6):

[Repelling blast](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/warlock#EldritchInvocations-388) says:

> When you hit a creature with [eldritch blast](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/eldritch-blast), you can push the creature up to 10 feet away from you in a straight line.

A gargantuan creature is a creature, so Repelling Blast would work.